# How to calculate the MSE of exponential smoothing model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I have a dataset of the daily stock price and volume, like this:

```
# A tibble: 124 x 4
   Period Date       Close  Volume
    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1      1 2017/10/16  144. 2001900
 2      2 2017/10/17  143. 2435600
 3      3 2017/10/18  143. 1734100
 4      4 2017/10/19  144. 2623100
 5      5 2017/10/20  145. 3369500
 6      6 2017/10/23  146. 2892200
 7      7 2017/10/24  146. 3319200
 8      8 2017/10/25  146. 2780400
 9      9 2017/10/26  146. 2146700
10     10 2017/10/27  146. 1869500
```

I try to use exponential smoothing model to forecast the future price

Now, I have four alpha <- c(0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.75). I want to use MSE to determine which alpha can provide the most accurate forecast results. Now the question is how to calculate the MSE?
the function sea() or HoltWinters() will not offer MSE of model.

Comment: The [Metrics package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Metrics/Metrics.pdf) is useful for a wide range of accuracy and error metrics. You might try it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me which function can deal with my question? I find the Metrics package direction, but it has 26 pages!

Comment: OK, I get it. The mse() function can calculate my answer. However, I can get the residuals from the HoltWinters() result. So, `result$residuals^2/ length(result$residuals)` is better.